# Erlang: Why does this fail with a 'badarith' exception?

Tags: erlang, closures

Is it possible to implement a closure in Erlang?

For example, how would I translate this snippet from Scheme?

```
(define (make-adder n)
  (lamdba (x) (+ x n)))
```

I've tried the following, but I'm clearly missing something.

```
make_adder(n) ->
    fun (x) -> x + n end.
```

Compiling this gives the error

```
Warning: this expression will fail with a 'badarith' exception
```

Comment: Guys, why's this being upvoted?  I'm embarrassed at how lame my question is!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't add atoms. Variables start with Capital Letters in erlang. words starting with lower case letters are atoms.

In other words your problem is not related to `fun`s at all, you just need to capitalize your variable names.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm deleting the question and going to bed!

Comment: Can't delete question... just going to bed.

Comment: Leave the question and change the title to 'Why do I get "this expression will fail with a 'badarith' exception"?' or something along those lines. That way all the other erlang beginners who'll make this mistake (I know I did) will easily find it when searching for the message.

Comment: I confirm that one beginner did get help reading this.
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
make_adder(N) ->
  fun (X) -> X + N end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables start with **Capital Letters** in erlang. 
words starting with lower case letters are atoms.